# How to disable selecting whole canvas in webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview, html5-canvas

I have few elements that are registered with event-listeners ('touchstart'). I add it into webview. Listeners work fine, but every time I touch canvas, it selects whole canvas (like normal DOM object), after small delay it executes callback from event-listener and then unselect canvas.

My question: is there any way to disable this selection because it's unnecessary and ugly?

Comment: Surprisingly only Chrome-mobile works like that. Opera works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team met this problem too, exactly the same as you described.

There's nothing wrong with your js code or touch handlers.

Just add a css property to your canvas element like this:

```
canvas{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

And this will fix your problem.